# How can I test if the DataContractSerializer was effectively replaced by XmlProtoSerializer?

Tags: c#, wcf, protobuf-net

I have a series of self-hosted WCF services (using `netTcpBinding`) that I want to enhance by using the fantastic **protobuf-net** serializer.

I configured both the client and the service endpoints with the custom behavior extensions as instructed in the documentation of the `ProtoEndpointBehavior` class [(see here)](https://code.google.com/p/protobuf-net/source/browse/trunk/protobuf-net/ServiceModel/ProtoEndpointBehavior.cs?r=303).  My tests ran fine from the very first try, however, I'm **very** skeptical of WCF-stuff running  fine at the very first try  ;)

Is there a simple way in which I can assert that the default `DataContractSerializer` was replaced by the `XmlProtoSerializer`?

I would really favor a test that can be also coded as part of a unit test.  I wouldn't like the protobuf-net library to be inadvertently disabled by careless tampering of the `.config` file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you call your service in wcf test client, you will see < proto/> tag in the body of response
[image: proto call]

If you configure your client to use proto behaviour and call service with "inadvertently disabled protobuf", your answer will be null because of different serializers. You can check it in your test

```
var address = new EndpointAddress( url );
var binding = GetBinding( address.Uri );
var factory = new ChannelFactory<TService>( binding, address );
factory.Endpoint.EndpointBehaviors.Add( CreateProtobufEndpointBehavior() );
var client = factory.CreateChannel();
var answer = client.GetSomeInt();

AssertAnswerIsNotNull(answer);
```

Comment: Thank you very much Ruslan, the WCF Test Client is new to me and seems to be certainly useful  (every day you learn something). However, regarding the Unit test, how would the Unit test detect if the config file was modified for both the client and server, disabling ProtoBuf.net?  It seems to me that I'm going to have to hardcode the serializer swap -  if only I'd knew how  :P

Comment: Add protobuf behaviour in your test _programmatically_ as in my example above. In this case your test will fail when proto disabled in your service config.

Comment: Can't find `CreateProtobufEndpointBehavior`. Is this the same as `new ProtoBuf.ServiceModel.ProtoEndpointBehavior()`?

Comment: Amir, yes it is